# 'Create Unit Test' Command in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio

I can't find the ["Create Unit Test" command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/developer-testing/getting-started/create-unit-tests-menu) in the context menu anymore. Did they remove it from VS2017?

Comment: Live Unit Testing in Visual Studio 2017 RC: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/18/live-unit-testing-visual-studio-2017-rc/

Comment: @duDE: I don't know how that is relevant? Are you implying that they removed the command in favor of live unit testing?

Comment: Well, that is about a RC (release candidate) of VS, not ready yet. And yes, you can use meantime the Live Unit Testing instead.

Comment: @duDE: Oh, I think you misunderstood. I can still use unit tests, it's just that the one command is missing. It's just a slight inconvenience because now I have to create the TestMethod manually. But I guess it will be implemented once it's done.

Comment: Despite this, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/developer-testing/getting-started/create-unit-tests-menu I also can't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Unit Tests context menu option missing in Visual Studio 2017?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42974497)/

Comment: @Michael Freidgeim: How can this be a duplicate of a question that hasn't even been asked back then?

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha
If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was removed, though I didn't really use it.  I recommend using Rusty Divine's [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/osmyn/906c917653a30864cb52dee02c36c14e):

Works great--all you have to do is type ut and then TAB.